# What is the difference between a trimmer and a trimmer console?

Tags: string-trimmer

What does the word **'Console'** in the model name signify?

[image]

I have used the 'compare' options but the feature comparison does not explain what 'Console' means. As far as I can tell the 'Console' version is bit bigger in size.

I only need a trimmer to tend the yards of my house (i.e. causal usage).

I attach more screenshots from the comparison screen for your reference.

[image: features]

[image: dimension]

Comment: Gotta hate when copywriters don't align their feature descriptions in any way, making comparison difficult... Also, you didn't ask what "skin" means on the other one. Weird naming.

Comment: The Width and Depth dimensions also don't match - Width on the first model has got to equal Depth on the other model. The redundancy in the first model's text plus the "gray rectangle of unreadability" in the second model are both terrible, As a retired technical writer, I can say that the copywriter is a disgrace to their profession.